# ExpiryMap is getting set but doesn't remember when the function is called again?

Tags: javascript, typescript, caching, browser-cache

what is the right way to use `expiry-map` in javascript/typescript

It seems to be getting set properly but seems like it forgets with end of the function.

This is my code.

```
import ExpiryMap from 'expiry-map'
const KEY_ACCESS_TOKEN = 'accessToken'
const cache = new ExpiryMap(10 * 1000)

export async function getChatGPTAccessToken(): Promise<string> {
  if (cache.get(KEY_ACCESS_TOKEN)) {
    return cache.get(KEY_ACCESS_TOKEN)
  }
  console.log("Couldnt find accessToken in cache", cache)
  const resp = await fetch('https://example.com/api/auth/session')
  const data = await resp.json().catch(() => ({}))
  if (!data.accessToken) {
    throw new Error('UNAUTHORIZED')
  }
  cache.set(KEY_ACCESS_TOKEN, data.accessToken)
  console.log("accessToken set to: ", data.accessToken);
  console.log("accessToken get from:", cache.get(KEY_ACCESS_TOKEN));// <-- it has the new value set, so it is getting set properly
  return data.accessToken
}
```

`getChatGPTAccessToken()` is being called from another file and it isn't part of any class.